# Prestashop automatically the code that appears in all descriptions

Tags: prestashop

I found that ... is it true that when I record there is automatically the code that appears in all descriptions that I record?

2.6.0.0

Thank you for your help

Comment: I mean to say following div <div id = "sconnect-is-installed" style = "display: none;"> 2.6.0.0 </ div>

Comment: Add more details to your question.

Comment: When I add the product "short description" and "description" then automatically added div and click save and stay btn.

Comment: I didn't see any `div` gets added automatically? Do you have installed any theme for frontend?

Comment: check this link: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/821267-code-2500-dans-la-description-apr%C3%A8s-modification/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such problem in Prestashop.

There are two ways ahead:

1. You installed a module or a template that created the problem
2. You added extensions to your browser causing this problem (check with another browser)